# R function no output loess span

Tags: r, function, output, loess

So I have written a function,that should find me the span for the `loess` function that corresponds to the degrees of freedom for an equation:

```
m <- function(x) x+4*cos(7*x)
x<-seq(-1,1,length=101)
```

to find the degrees of freedom I used the identity matrix

```
y<-diag(101)
slp<-matrix(0,nrow=101,ncol=101)
snw<- is the hat matrix
```

here my function, I want it to output the span for which is approximately equal to the same degrees of freedom in hat matrix `snw` (sum of it diagonals)

```
y<-diag(101)
dflp<-function(span,value)
       {
        for(q in 1:301)
          {          
          for(i in 1:101)
            {
            slp[,i]<-predict(loess(y[,i]~x,span=span[q]),newdata=x)
            }
          if(sum(diag(slp))-value==0)
            {
             cat("span:",format(span[q]),"\n")
             break
            }
          }
        }
```

It doesn't seem to output anything, and the value of `q` is always 7.

Thank you.

NOTE: This is not homework.

Comment: My first guess is you've forgotten that floating-point variables will not produce `zero` as a difference result.  Try `abs(diag(slp)-value)<1e-10`

Comment: I'm still not getting any output from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be anything wrong with your logic. You are performing a grid search on a number of candidate `span`. You stop searching when the resulting degree of freedom matches the one given by `snw`.

You get no returned value from your function `dflp`, because you lack a `return(span[q])` at the end of your function.

Another suggestion I would give, is similar to a comment above. "Convergence" is never judged by exact 0, but up to some tolerance. Normally we use relative tolerance:

```
abs(diag(slp)-value) / value < 1e-6  ## tol = 1e-6
```